# Regex to find string or numbers between string with loose parameters

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to parse a large file for a specific score in semi-structured data. The desired output is a number 0,1,2,3, or if not explicitly stated, NEGATIVE=0. How can I select just the number or negative, while accounting for the variability in the test code format? Thank you!

Desired output: 2 2 0 0 3 0 0

```r
a <- c("COMP): intermediate (score 2+)",
       "COMP) intermediate (FOCAL 2+)", 
       "COMP) IS NEGATIVE (0)", 
       "COMP) is negative (0)",
       "COMP is POSITIVE (3+)",
       "COMP) NEGATIVE IN", 
       "COMP) NEGATIVE (0)")

COMPpattern <- "COMP\\)[:|\\s]*(.*?)(?=\\)*)"

str_match(toupper(a), COMPpattern)[,2]
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the only number present in the string is the desired number? example seems to suggest that is the case. If yes, the problem is quite easy. Filter by number "[0-9]", if none is found return "NEGATIVE=0" or whatever string you desire.

Comment: Do you always want to return `0` if there is `negative` in the string? Try `ifelse(grepl("(?i)negative", a), 0, sub(".*\\(\\D*(\\d+).*", "\\1", a))`

Comment: Thanks. Caveat is that test code is a short substring of a much longer string that may have later numbers or negative. if NEGATIVE is within ~3 words after a (, it's relevant, and for a number, if it's within 3 words and/or before a ), then it's also relevant.

Comment: This has become rather vague. Something like [this](https://ideone.com/K0tKEO)? [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/NU76Uj/1).

Comment: IF you can rely on the "within 3 words of a parenthesis" you can do a regex that is a little more simples \d(?=\W{1,3}\)) [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/r75Ozz/1) for numbers. No reference to COMP is needed.

Comment: Sadly, need the context of COMP given this is a subset of the string. Wiktor, can you explain your line above? Some are truly NA if the string is absent, so would prefer to keep as negative or number ->grepl(negative) to make 0, and then keep any remaining number, and anything left is truly NA. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the number you want is always the first (of possibly multiple) numbers in each string, then you can just extract the first and ignore the rest.

```r
out <- as.integer(stringr::str_extract(a, "\\d+"))
out
# [1]  2  2  0  0  3 NA  0
```

Or, with base R,

```r
out <- suppressWarnings(as.integer(gsub("^\\D*(\\d+).*", "\\1", a)))
```

From here, to change the "negative" to 0, we can choose from two options (depending on your needs):

```r
### if "negative" triggers 0 only when no other number
replace(out, is.na(out) & grepl("negative", a, ignore.case = TRUE), 0)
# [1] 2 2 0 0 3 0 0

### if "negative" should override any number found, remove is.na(out)
replace(out, grepl("negative", a, ignore.case = TRUE), 0)
```

(as reassign that into `out`).

(I recognize that this method ignores many of your "parens" and "words" constraints, I'm not sure if this is an over-simplification of the problem.)